# How to use listagg with querydsl?

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, jpa, querydsl

I have a query as shown below;

```
SELECT 
   .
   .
   LISTAGG(DISTINCT CC.POPULATION, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CC.POPULATION ASC),
   .
   .
FROM COUNTRY C
     JOIN CITY CC ON C.ID = CC.COUNTRY_ID
--WHERE 
GROUP BY C.ID;
```

I should be implement with querydsl for custom filtering and sorting operations but I got "No pattern found for LISTAGG" error

```
JPAQuery<Tuple> jpaQuery = jpaQueryFactory.select(         
            SQLExpressions.listagg(QCity.city.POPULATION, ",")
            .withinGroup()
            .orderBy(QCity.city.POPULATION.asc())
    )
            .from(QCountry.country)
            .join(QCity.city).on(QCountry.country.id.eq(QCity.city.countryId))
            //.where(custom filtering)
            .groupBy(QCountry.country.id);

jpaQuery.fetch();
```

I try to add custom template like this but I couldn't succeed. Also my querydsl-sql version is 4.2.1

```
StringTemplate customPopulationTemplate = Expressions.stringTemplate(
            "(LISTAGG(DISTINCT {0},',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY {0} ASC))", QCity.city.population);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Hibernate 5.2.18, you can use the MetadataBuilderContributor utility to customize the MetadataBuilder even if you are bootstrapping via JPA.

The `MetadataBuilderContributor` interface can be implemented like this:

```
public class SqlFunctionsMetadataBuilderContributor
    implements MetadataBuilderContributor {
     
 @Override
 public void contribute(MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder) {
    metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction(
        "group_concat",
        new StandardSQLFunction(
            "group_concat",
            StandardBasicTypes.STRING
        )
    );
 }
}
```

And, we can provide the SqlFunctionsMetadataBuilderContributor via the hibernate.metadata_builder_contributor configuration property:

```
<property>
    name="hibernate.metadata_builder_contributor"
    value="com.vladmihalcea.book.hpjp.hibernate.query.function.SqlFunctionsMetadataBuilderContributor"
</property>
```

Reference: https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-sql-function-jpql-criteria-api-query/

Answer (score 1):

Window functions are not included in the JPQL specification and as such not available in any JPA implementation. You could register these functions yourself using [custom functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41369853/2104280).

However, after this, these functions still won't be accessible in QueryDSL. You're stealing from the `SQLExpressions` here to obtain a window expression. These methods live in `SQLExpressions` for a reason: they only work with `querydsl-sql` and not with `querydsl-jpa` (again, because JPA itself does not support window functions). So after registering your custom function, you will still have to extend `JPQLTemplates` to include the template for your custom window function.

You'd do this like this:

```
public class MyTemplates extends JPQLTemplates {

    public MyTemplates() {
        add(SQLOps.ROWNUMBER, "ROW_NUMBER({0})");
    }

}
```

And then use it as follows:

```java
new JPAQuery(entityManager, new MyTemplates()).from(entity).select(rowNumber())
```

---

Alternatively you could look into the [`blaze-persistence-querydsl`](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.5/core/manual/en_US/#querydsl-integration) extension, which has out of the box support for window functions (and many other features) for JPQL. For example:

```java
QCat cat = QCat.cat;

BlazeJPAQuery<Tuple> query = new BlazeJPAQuery<Tuple>(entityManager, criteriaBuilderFactory).from(cat)
    .select(cat.name, JPQLNextExpressions.rowNumber(), JPQLNextExpressions.lastValue(cat.name).over().partitionBy(cat.id));

List<Tuple> fetch = query.fetch();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try these :)